# Compiler design frontend calculation in the main function for Clang and Zig

Tags: clang, compiler-development, zig

I have started reading the source code of `clang` and `zig-lang`.
Unfortunately, the source codes are complicated and I am not able to find out where is frontend of these compilers are called in the main function.

In `clang`, the closer place I have found is [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/examples/clang-interpreter/main.cpp#L177) but it does not look like processing the compilation frontend.

In `zig-lang`, the main function is even messier and very hard to understand. I just could find the de facto main function (main0) [here](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L262).

Though, explaining the stages of these compilers and pointing to their code is appreciated, just the point of where frontends computations are called is sufficient for me.

Comment: Hello! To make more easy to people to answer you, I suggest to try to edit and reformulate in a more concrete question. Like ¿Where is the [concrete thing]? or ¿How it works [something concrete]?. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The main zig compiler is executed from [Compilation.performAllTheWork](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/Compilation.zig#L1540). This function loops over all the compilation items and compiles them. ([main()](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/main.zig#L169) → [buildOutputType](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/main.zig#L1942-L1945) → [updateModule](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/main.zig#L2100) → [Compilation.update](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/Compilation.zig#L1324) → Compilation.performAllTheWork)

Stage1 (the default compiler in zig 0.8.0, written in C++) is called when stage1_module items are found in the work queue from [Compilation.updateStage1Module](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/Compilation.zig#L3336). The bulk of compilation happens from [codegen_build_object](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/fe117d9961c3622fda5c359733d01de686509af0/src/stage1/codegen.cpp#L9237) (called from [zig_stage1_build_object](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/15278b7f4b74e659fd968571cb9b96929da3d82c/src/stage1/stage1.cpp#L130))

Stage2 (the work-in-progress faster compiler written in Zig) is more tightly integrated into the work queue because it supports incremental compilation and is called in [these branches](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/c558a1ae26eaa8c59e97e80ec01990e35ef50f3a/src/Compilation.zig#L1562-L1696) of the work queue switch.

---

Clang starts somewhere, maybe in [clang.lib.frontend.CompilerInvocation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.cpp)?